# Laravel Query to result with sub array no eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, relational-database, laravel-5.5, entity-relationship

please help me in my project at school. How can i query in laravel controller something like this situation.
I have three tables:
Shipping_table and Shipping_products and tbl_products, now my table structure is this:

Shipping table:

```
Ship_ID (INT AUTO INC)
AMOUNT (DOUBLE,2)
NAME (VARCHAR)
SHIP_DATE (DATE)
RECEIVER (VARCHAR)
```

Shipping_products:

```
ID (INT AUTO INC)
Ship_id (foreign key from shipping table)
Product_id
```

Products_table:

```
Product_id (Auto Inc)
name(varchar)
Qty(int)
Description (varchar)
```

now what i want is having a query result like this:
I want to get all in the shipping table and in sub-array i want to get the products that is being listed in shipping_products with the desired shipping id.

Something a result like this: EXAMPLE I HAVE 2 Shipping_table values

```
Array(2) {
 [0] Array(4) {
  ['Ship_id'] "1"
  ['Amount'] "10000"
  ['Ship_date'] "1995-12-11"
  ['Ship_products'] Array(3)
      ['id'] "1" Array(2)
           ['product_id'] "5"
           ['name'] "Product 1"
      ['id'] "2" Array(2)
           ['product_id'] "6"
           ['name'] "Product 2"
      ['id'] "3" Array(2)
           ['product_id'] "10"
           ['name'] "Product 15"

 }
 [1] Array(4) {
   ['Ship_id'] "2"
   ['Amount'] "15000"
   ['Ship_date'] "1995-12-15"
   ['Ship_products'] Array(2)
      ['id'] "1" Array(2)
           ['product_id'] "5"
           ['name'] "Product 1"
      ['id'] "2" Array(2)
           ['product_id'] "6"
           ['name'] "Product 2"
 }
}
```

Comment: MySQL query results are *flat tables*. What you want a query **and** php code to move it into a special array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL part is easy (using `JOINS`)

```
SELECT * 
FROM Shipping S
LEFT JOIN Shipping_Products SP
  ON SP.Ship_Id=S.Ship_Id
LEFT JOIN Products P
  ON P.Product_id=SP.Product_id
```

The `php` part is more complicated, as you have to get the results in a loop and detect changes in `Ship_id` and `Product_id` and put in the resulting array.

Since this is homework .. I'll leave it as an exercise ...

---

**THIS IS A QUICK ALGORITHM EXAMPLE - untested but logically sound.**

```
$cur_ship = '';
$cur_prod = '';
$results  = array();
foreach ($resultset as $key => $row) {
   if ($cur_ship != $row['Ship_id']) {
      $cur_ship = $row['Ship_id'];
      $cur_prod = '';
      $results[$cur_ship] = array();
      // Fill ship info from $row
   }
   if ($cur_prod != $row['Product_id']) {
      $cur_prod = $row['Product_id'];
      $results[$cur_ship][$cur_prod] = array();
      // Fill Product info from $row
   }
   // FILL OUR $results[$cur_ship][$cur_prod] from $row
}
```

Comment: hello sir, can you give me a link as example for the php code?.. i dont have a clue on how to do it

Comment: Can you connect and execute and get the result set into `php`? if so< I can give you the algorithm . Connecting and getting results is out of scope for me

Comment: hello sir. i did like this, 
$shippings = DB::table('shipping_table')
        ->select('*')
        ->leftJoin('shipping_products', function ($join) {
         $join->on('shipping_products.shipping_id','=','shipping_table.shipping_id');
        })
        ->leftJoin('products', function ($join) {
         $join->on('products.product_id', '=', 'shipping_products.product_id');
        })->get(); after query what would i do?

Comment: Like I said, getting the result into the array for Laravel  is out of scope for me. Once you learn that, you can use my code example above